# Determine when both fragments are visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would have thought this was pretty easy, but it's proving more difficult than I imagined.  I just want to determine when both fragments are visible on the screen in one of my fragments.  I'm not sure if `onCreate` is the best place to do it, but I tried `onResume`, `onActivityCreated`, `onResume`, `onCreateView` and `onAttach`.  I'm thinking the fragments are aren't actually visible, to the code, until later, but not sure.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>
    <fragment android:name="com.app.Fragment1"
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

    <fragment android:name="com.app.Fragment2"  
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
</LinearLayout>

public class Fragment2 extends SherlockListFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        final Fragment1 f1 = (Fragment1)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        final Fragment2 f2 = (Fragment2)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

        Boolean isVisible = (f1 != null && f1.isVisible() && f2 != null && f2.isVisible());
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`onStart()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart%28%29) is when the fragment is visible to the user, so I suggest putting your `isVisible` code in `onResume` just to be safe.

Comment: I got it to  work by using `isAdded` instead of `isVisible`.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ah, well a fragment is added in a different method of the lifecycle, but I'm glad you got it working!